# Nielsen Chang exercise 4.10

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, nielsen-and-chuang

I' m trying to figure out how to decompose unitary operator U using only Rx and Ry rotations. I understand that I must use result of exercise 4.8 ($ U = e^{i\alpha}R_n(\theta)$). But I don't understand how, my thoughts is use Bloch vector coordinates and place it instead n-vector coordinate and try to solve using this, but I think it is not correct way. Can anyone help me or give some insights how to solve this exercise?

Comment: Please add the text of the exercise in full.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem 4.10 of Nielsen and Chuang's text asks the reader to produce an $XY$-decomposition of a single-qubit unitary $U$, in parallel with the $ZY$-decomposition given in Theorem 4.1 of the text. That is, the problem asks to show that any single-qubit unitary $U$ can be written as
$$ U = e^{i \alpha} R_x(\beta) R_y(\gamma) R_x(\delta)
$$
for appropriate choices of $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta$.

Certainly, we could proceed along similar lines as the text does for the $ZY$-decomposition of Theorem 4.1, producing the result essentially from scratch. Alternatively, we could simply use Theorem 4.1 and do a "change of reference", to interchange the $x$ and $z$ axes. Let's proceed the latter route and see how this works.

We know that the Hadamard $H$ (which we quickly note is unitary and self-inverse) implements the appropriate swap between $x$ and $z$, while sending $y$ to $-y$. So instead of working with $U$ directly, consider
$$ U' = H U H^{-1} = H U H
$$
which is the frame-rotated $U$. Using Theorem 4.1 of the text, we can produce a $ZY$-decomposition of $U'$.
$$ U' = e^{i\alpha} R_z(\beta) R_y(\gamma) R_z(\delta)
$$
What does this imply for $U$? We will see that the above implies an $XY$-decomposition for $U$.
\begin{align}
U = HU'H &= e^{i\alpha} (H R_z(\beta) H)(H R_y(\gamma)H)(HR_z(\delta) H) \\
&= e^{i\alpha} R_x(\beta) R_y(-\gamma) R_x(\delta).
\end{align}
Notice the change in sign for $\gamma$ that occurs since $H Y H = -Y$. Regardless, we have $U$ written in the required form.

As a final elaboration, this argument could be generalized. We could choose any two orthogonal axes $\hat{n}, \hat{m}$ for rotations in our decomposition, using the fact that we can always frame-rotate to the $z$ and $x$ axes.

Comment: Thanks, understood!

Comment: I tried to change $R_z$ rotation with $R_x$ rotations but I always got $HR_x(\beta)R_y(-\gamma)R_x(\delta)H$ And stopped at this moment without knowing how transform this in desired view.)) I didn't figure it out before this trick)